# How to store data from the database into array and display it to bar chart?

Tags: php, laravel, charts

| id | title | price | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Japanese Book | 150 | 55 |
| 2 | Flowers | 75 | 0 |
| 3 | Dictionary | 100 | 15 |
| 4 | Encyclopedia | 250 | 10 |

This is my first time doing bar chart and I'm trying to display data from my database in a bar chart but the problem I encounter is that it only displays the last data in my database which is Encyclopedia but I'm trying to display all of them. What should I change/add in my code below because I believe that my mistake is the code in my controller.

```
public function barChart(){

    $data = product::all();

    foreach($data as $data){
        $prod_name = [$data->title];
        $prod_sold = [$data->sold];
    }

    return view('bar-chart',compact('prod_name','prod_sold'));
}
```

Below is my code in my blade file,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="map_canvas">
  
           <canvas id="myChart" width="auto" height="100"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($prod_name) ?>,
        datasets: [{
            label: '',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($prod_sold); ?>,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(31, 58, 147, 1)',
                'rgba(37, 116, 169, 1)',
                'rgba(92, 151, 191, 1)',
                'rgb(200, 247, 197)',
                'rgb(77, 175, 124)',
                'rgb(30, 130, 76)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(31, 58, 147, 1)',
                'rgba(37, 116, 169, 1)',
                'rgba(92, 151, 191, 1)',
                'rgb(200, 247, 197)',
                'rgb(77, 175, 124)',
                'rgb(30, 130, 76)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                max: 200,
                min: 0,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 50
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'Custom Chart Title'
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the variable `$prod_name` an array that contains all of your titles and the same as `$prod_sold`, which contains all sold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables of `$prod_name` and `$pro_sold` are two arrays, which contain the data fetched from the database if I guess it correctly.

So, you made two mistakes.

1. Assign multiple variables to a local variable `$prod_name` multiple times, so the `$prod_name` only store the last variable in your loop.
2. As you can see, you init the variables `$prod_name` and `$prod_sole` in a foreach loop, which was a bad code practice. You should init them outside the foreach function.

Check the updated code below:

```
public function barChart(){

    $data = product::all();

    // init variable
    $prod_name = array();
    $prod_sold = array();
    foreach($data as $data){
        //append a new variable to an array
        $prod_name[] = $data->title;
        $prod_sold[] = $data->sold;
    }

    return view('bar-chart',compact('prod_name','prod_sold'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data into array, you can push the data into array.

```
$data = product::all();

// empty array declaration
$prod_name = array();
$prod_sold = array();


foreach($data as $data){
    array_push($prod_name, $data->title);
    array_push($prod_sold, $data->sold);
}
```

To check the contents in array you can dd or echo it. Ex:

```
dd($prod_name);
```

So you can return it to bar chart with array variables

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Amri and the info about dd, I'll make sure to use it in my future development.